# Find clicked icon on web page and click similar icon on another web page using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

I’ve been whacking my brains for far too long on this and trawled the internet yet I can’t find a proper solution to this.
I will really appreciate it if someone can help me get out of this maize I find myself in. (If I could I’d buy you a beer )

I have tried all I know, tested all I could, but can’t find a stable solution.
The solution needs to be stable please. Hence my problem.

I can’t publish any **PYTHON** code I used because it just would not make sense.

**SCENARIO**:
There are 4 icons (categories-A/B/C/D) on main web page.
I need to identify which icon that was clicked by the user. This can be any of the 4 icons but only 1 can be selected/clicked at a time. The user selection is random.
Once it’s known which Category-Icon was clicked then I want to open a new Firefox tab (which has the same Category-Icons layout) and have the code click the same Category-Icon as on the main web page.
(switching to a new tab and back in Firefox I can do)

HTML below of the main web page where one of the icons was clicked.
#NOTE:
The key words that shows active icon is
**"split-item active"** (last one – “category-D”).

and word that shows active icon is **“white”** (last one – “category-D”).

```
    <ul class="split-list">

    <li class="split-item">
    <div class="category-icon icon-cat-A "></div>
    <div class="category-text">category-A</div>
    </li>
    <li class="split-item">
    <div class="category-icon icon-cat-B"></div>
    <div class="category-text">category-B </div>
    </li>
    <li class="split-item">
    <div class="category-icon icon-cat-C"></div>
    <div class="category-text">category-C</div>
    </li>
    <li class="split-item active">
    <div class="category-icon icon-cat-D-white">
    </div><div class="category-text">category-D</div>
    </li>
    <li class="active-bg"></li></ul>


    

**ACTIVE/MAIN WEB PAGE:**

INNER HTML

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-A"></div><div class="category-text">category-A</div></li>

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-B"></div><div class="category-text">category-B</div></li>

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-C"></div><div class="category-text">category-C</div></li>

    <li class="split-item active"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-D-white"></div><div class="category-text">category-D</div></li>


OUTER HTML

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-A"></div><div class="category-text">category-A</div></li>

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-B"></div><div class="category-text">category-B</div></li>

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-C"></div><div class="category-text">category-C</div></li>

    <li class="split-item active"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-D-white"></div><div class="category-text">category-D</div></li>



X-Path 

    /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[1]
    /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]
    /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[3]
    /html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[4]




**NEW WEB PAGE (no icons clicked) on which I want the code to click the same selected icon as on main web page.**

INNER HTML

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-A"></div><div class="category-text"> category-A</div>

    </li><li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-B"></div><div class="category-text"> category-B</div>

    </li><li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-C"></div><div class="category-text">category-C</div>

    </li><li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-D"></div><div class="category-text">category-D</div>

    </li><li class="active-bg"></li>


OUTER HTML

    <ul class="split-list">

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-A"></div><div class="category-text">category-A</div></li>

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-B"></div><div class="category-text">category-B</div></li>

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-C"></div><div class="category-text">category-C</div></li>

    <li class="split-item"><div class="category-icon icon-cat-D"></div><div class="category-text">category-D</div></li>

    <li class="active-bg"></li></ul>



X-Path

    /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div[4]/ul/li[1]
    /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div[4]/ul/li[2]
    /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div[4]/ul/li[3]
    /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div[4]/ul/li[4]
```

**THANK YOU**

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

First get the element selected using:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.split-list .active .category-icon')
```

From this element you need to get the className used for the icon you want to select in the next tab.

```
icon_class_name = el.get_attribute('className').split()[1]
```

*(The above could be improve to ensure you get the proper class)*

Once you get the className, go to your second tab (as provided you know how!)
Then use the class name found and click on it

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'.split-list .{icon_class_name}').click()
```

If the click does not work you might need to click on the parent element. You will need to get all parent elements and find the proper match to click on.

```
parent_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.split-list .category-icon')

for parent_el in parent_elements:
    els = parent_el.find_element_by_css_selector(f'.{icon_class_name}')
    if len(els) > 0:
        parent_el.click()
        break
else:
    // Else here is used if we never break.
    print("Could not find the element matching {icon_class_name}")
```

**UPDATE** 
Since the className will be appended with `-white` when selected, just remove this part from the className

```
icon_class_name = el.get_attribute('className').split()[1].replace('-white', '')
```

Update the the value of the element you are looking for to allow to find an element that is selected on the new website. (Assuming the class my append -white or anything else too)

```
els = parent_el.find_element_by_css_selector(f'[class*="{icon_class_name}"]')
```

Comment: Thank you for the input Nick.
I will certainly try it.

Comment: Getting Exception errors :-(

browser.find_element_by_css_selector(f'.split-list .{icon_class_name}').click()

Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
 Message: Unable to locate element: .split-list .icon-others-white
 File "D:\Webauto\main icons-002.py", line 81, in <module>

    parent_elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.split-list .category-icon')

Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
 Message: Unable to locate element: .icon-others-white
 File "D:\Webauto\main icons-002.py", line 120, in <module>

Comment: Think I got this one

print("START - find in CAT-D")

try:
    if browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.icon-category-D-white') != 1:
        print("FOUND - in CAT-D")

except NoSuchElementException:

        print("NOT FOUND - in CAT-D")

browser.implicitly_wait(5)

I tried this with all the categories
Same script repeated but with the different categories and only this one echo/print "FOUND".
Others echo/print "NOT FOUND"

Comment: The class is not the same for this one. On the first website it is ```icon-cat-D-white``` and on the second it is ```icon-cat-D```. So basically it is true, the element won't be found on the second website. If it was reverse, you could have use ```[class*=icon-cat-D]```, in your case you need logic to only keep the first part (without -white)

Comment: Looking at the html code, seems related to the item being selected. You might just replace the ```-white``` with empty. ```icon_class_name = el.get_attribute('className').split()[1].replace('-white', '') and change the cssSelector with ```[class*=icon-cat-D]```. See updated answer

Comment: @AndreVorster as this helped you out? Kind of wandering for the beer ;)

Comment: Nic.

Thank you for the reply.!
I've been busy with some other stuff and have not tried this out yet.

What you say makes sense about he "white space". With this you answered something I was working on.

As for the beer - Anytime man.! It's nice summer weather here in Cape Town.